# way to move from one color to another keeping the brightness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to develop a module in javascript that will allow to load an image and change the color of a selected part. I almost succeeded (i think), because I get to do the color changes for most colors respecting the saturation and brightness, so the shadow and light (I use the HSL and RGB). 
Then comes my problem: if the brightness is too high the result is médiodre especially if I use blue as the color to get.

Here the function i use to transform pixels
I use three colors for my fonction (two variable per color one for hsl and one for rgb)
One reference color (hslOrigin or OriginColor) that the user selected firstly
One color for the pixel transformed (hsl)
and one color that represents the destination color (hslDestination or DestionationColor)

```js
function recolorPants(OriginColor, DestinationColor, img) {
 var canvas = document.getElementById("resultCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
 
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var data = imgData.data;

 var maskdata = window.initMask(mask); //function to initiate the part of image i want to change

 var hslOrigin = rgbToHsl(OriginColor.r, OriginColor.g, OriginColor.b);
 var hslDestination = rgbToHsl(DestinationColor.r, DestinationColor.g, DestinationColor.b);
  
 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
  
  if(((maskdata[i + 0])== 128) && ((maskdata[i + 1])== 128) && ((maskdata[i + 2])== 128))
  {
   red = data[i + 0];
   green = data[i + 1];
   blue = data[i + 2];
   alpha = data[i + 3];
   
   var hsl = rgbToHsl(red, green, blue); //hsl from image source
   
   
   if((Math.abs(hslOrigin.h - hsl.h) <= 0.15)  ){
    if((hslOrigin.l < 0.7)){
                  
    var newRgb = hslToRgb(((hsl.h/hslOrigin.h ) *hslDestination.h) , ((hsl.s/hslOrigin.s) *hslDestination.s), ((hsl.l / hslOrigin.l) *hslDestination.l));
    data[i + 0] = newRgb.r;
    data[i + 1] = newRgb.g;
    data[i + 2] = newRgb.b;
    }else{
     var newRgb = hslToRgb(((hsl.h/hslOrigin.h ) *hslDestination.h) , ((hsl.s/hslOrigin.s) *hslDestination.s), hsl.l);
     
     data[i + 0] = newRgb.r;
     data[i + 1] = newRgb.g;
     data[i + 2] = newRgb.b;
    }
   }
  }
    }
 
 var canvas2 = document.getElementById("TheCanvas");
 var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
 
 ctx2.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}
```

i may be not clear, i will add more explanation if needed.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried a small project which manipulated colors manually and I finally caved and used tinycolor.js. So glad I did. If you are up for looking at external libraries, this one was able to alleviate a lot of headache on my end

Comment: You seem to be missing something crucial: a specific question.

Comment: Thaks for the answers. I will edit the question with specific question.

 thks

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will edit the question with specific question.
My question is : how I should manage brightness from one color to a high brightness level to a low brightness level color? (example: when I spend light green to blue, rather than to obtain a certain spot light blue I get white. this makes the result rather poor.)
 thks